# SPRING: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'spittr.welcome' for locale 'en_US'

Tags: java, spring, jsp, internationalization, resources

I'm studying Spring and doing exercise by following the book "Spring 4 in action".
I have a problem with a String in a jsp file that should be read from a property file called messages.properties.

My configuration is the following:

I'm using Maven

I've put the properties files inside the following path:

```
src/main/resources/messages.properties
src/main/resources/messages_it.properties
```

Inside the messages.properties I have defined the following property:

```
spittr.welcome=Welcome to Spittr!
```

Inside the messages.properties I have defined the following property:

```
spittr.welcome=Benvenuto su Spittr!
```

This is how I have defined the ResourceBundleMessageSource in the DispatcherServlet class:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
}
```

This is the file registerForm.jsp located inside the path src/main/webapp/WEB-INF-views

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sf" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
        <title>Spittr</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/style.css" />" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><s:message code="spittr.welcome" /></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the page is rendered, if my browser has a locale = en, it gives the following error:  **javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'spittr.welcome' for locale 'en_US'.**

When the locale is it (italian), the page works with no problems, so the property is actually read.

If I put the file src/main/resources/messages_en.properties, the problem is solved, but my question is: **Shouldn't the messages.properties file be used when the locale is not found?**

I've also tried with ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource, but I have the same problem.

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

I tried different ResourceBundleMessageSource/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource options, but it seems not to working.

Do you have any ideas about what I'm doing wrong? If you need more info, let me know.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually caused by a misconfiguration in the basename. If the message files are located in the WEB-INF folder, the path to the bundle must also be put as part of the setBasename() method, like this:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    messageSource.setBasename("WEB-INF/messages");
    return messageSource;
}
```